# sparql query to get all versions of python

Tags: sparql

I tried to get all versions released of python from wiki but I'm getting confused with the notation of instance and property.

How can I get it to work?

```
# get all version release for python

select ?version ?versionLabel
where
{
wdt:P5568 wd:Q3331189 ?version;

          
 SERVICE wikibase:label {
    bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" .
    
}          

}
```

also tried:

```
# get all version release for python

select ?version ?versionLabel ?app ?appLabel
where
{
?app wdt:P5568 wd:Q3331189;
     wdt:P348 ?version;

          
 SERVICE wikibase:label {
    bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" .
    
}          

}
```

Comment: I don't get what you want, you queries are totally mixed up. Are you asking for the versions of the Python programming language itself? Or of some packages?

Comment: getting version of Python itself is `# get all version release for python

select ?version ?versionLabel 
where
{
wd:Q28865 p:P348/ps:P348 ?version
          
 SERVICE wikibase:label {
    bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" .
    
}          

}`

Comment: @UninformedUser This is exactly what I was looking for. Please post as answer. I'll accept it!!! Thank You for the answer. Also, what's the difference between wdt, wd and p??